# My operator overload isn't returning in my int main?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a code that adds 2 octal numbers and then converts the sum to decimal using operator overloading. However, whenever I try and use my convert operator($), I get "$num1 was not declared in this scope". can anyone help me?

Note: I know some of the things can be changed for simplicity but it has to be this way because that's the way my teacher wants it. My main problem is calling the operator in the main. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <algorithm>//reverse
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int gnum=0;

class Oct{
private:
    int number;//Base 10
    vector <int> octnum;//separated out number
public:
    Oct();
    void input();//input 457
    void setNum(int);//sending setNum a base 10 number(457)
    void operator+ (Oct);//if(sum>7)sum-8
    int operator$ ();//converts sum to base 10
    void display();
    vector <int> octSum;//vector of added numbers
};

Oct::Oct()
{
    number = 0;
    octnum.push_back(0);
}

void Oct::input()
{
    cout<<"Enter your number: ";
    cin>>number;
    gnum = number;
}

void Oct::setNum(int num)
{
    while(num!=0)
    {
        octnum.push_back(num%10);
        num=num/10;
    }
    octnum.push_back(0);
    if(octnum[0]==0)
    {
        octnum.erase(octnum.begin());
    }
}

void Oct::display()
{
    for(int i = 0;i<octSum.size();i++)
    {
        cout<<octSum[i];
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

void Oct::operator+ (Oct num2)
{
    int carry = 0;
    int add = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<octnum.size();i++)
    {
        add = octnum[i]+num2.octnum[i]+carry;

        if(add>7)
        {
            add=add-8;
            carry = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            carry = 0;
        }
        octSum.push_back(add);
    }
}

int Oct::operator$ ()
{
    for(int i = 0;i<octSum.size();i++)
    {
        octSum[i]=octSum[i]*int(pow(8,i)+0.5);
    }
    reverse(octSum.begin(),octSum.end());
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<octSum.size();i++)
    {
        sum = sum + octSum[i]*int(pow(10,octSum.size()-1-i)+0.5);
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    Oct num1,num2;
    num1.input();
    num1.setNum(gnum);
    num2.input();
    num2.setNum(gnum);
    num1+num2;
    int j = $num1;
    num1.display();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You cannot just invent a new operator symbol. You can only overload operators that already exist in the language. Also, little-known fact: `$` is a valid character in an identifier, so `$num1` is just a (weird-looking) name (and the compiler complains because that name wasn't declared before; it would complain the same way about, say, `Snum1`). Similarly, `int operator$ ();` is just a normal member function (also with a weird but valid name).

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense. Thank you

Comment: Quick Question, my teacher says if that doesn't work then use the ^ symbol but I keep getting errors, do you know if I can overload the ^ symbol or not?

Comment: `octSum[i]=octSum[i]*int(pow(8,i)+0.5);` -- There is no need to introduce floating point functions such as `pow` and calculations (adding `0.5`) in an integer-based solution.  You are risking rounding errors by using such constructs in your program.   Your entire program can be done using integer and/or integer-based variables, functions, and calculations.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: It is implementation-defined whether `$` is a valid character in an identifer. Don't use it if you care about portability.

Comment: You can overload `^`, but it's a binary operator, requiring two arguments. `^num1` is not syntactically valid; it has to be `something ^ somethingElse`

Comment: I must say your teacher is quite, uh, *eccentric*, what with insisting on using overloaded operators where it doesn't make any sense; and operators that don't exist in nature, to boot. Why is it that `num1.display();` is OK, but `int j = num1.convert();` is not OK? If anything, `display()` is much more naturally implementable as an overloaded `operator<<`

Comment: Change `int j = $num1;` to `int j = num1.operator$();`

Answer (score 0):

`$` is not an operator in C++. It is just a character without any specific meaning. Whether it is supported as physical character in the source code is implementation-defined and it is also implementation-defined whether it will be parsed as part of an identifier. If it is parsed as part of an identifier, it will become part of the token, the same way as characters `a` to `z` do.

Apparently your compiler is supporting `$` as source file character and as character in identifiers and therefore you are not overloading an operator, you are defining a normal member function with the name `operator$` and you are referencing an identifier `$num1` in `main` that has not been declared beforehand.

You cannot invent new operators.

Comment: Thanks! Quick Question, my teacher says if that doesn't work then use the ^ symbol but I keep getting errors, do you know if I can overload the ^ symbol or not?

Comment: @RohitSingh `^` can be overloaded, but it is a binary operator. It needs an operand on the left-hand and right-hand side. You are trying to use it as if it was unary.

Comment: If the implementation doesn't define `$` as allowable in identifiers, then `operator$` is two preprocessing tokens (`operator` and `$`)

Comment: @M.M Yes you are right, I will fix that. Btw, looking at the C++17 standard it seems that the "implementation-defined" part of the identifier grammar has been removed, but `$` is not part of the allowed universal-character-name list. Is it technically not allowed anymore?

Comment: @walnut Not sure, although there is always the provision that implementations can add their own extensions so long as no strictly-confirming program is affected